# Is it possible to call contract that has no function?

Tags: go-ethereum, evm, bytecode

For example I have a contract that has the following bytecode `0x433d52593df3` (contract that returns the current block number if called). How could I call such a contract?

Comment: Elaborate your question a little bit. How did the bytes `0x433d52593df3` come about, or from where?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can; send a standard transaction to it.

Solidity compiles *functions/methods* into a custom `switch/case` pattern applied to the `calldata` sent to the smart contract with the tx. Following that rule is not mandatory, just a best practice.

If you want to experiment your *functionless* smart contract using Solidity/Yul, you can start with something like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract ReturnBlockNumber {
    fallback() external {
        assembly {
            mstore(0x0, number())
            return(0x0, 32)
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use Remix to call that contract, check the *Low Level Interaction* panel.

Side note about `0x433d52593df3`: really clever use of `3d` instead of `6000` ;)